# Function template-value overloaded by value's type

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

In a variadric non-type template, each value on the template list has its own type:

```cpp
template <typename T> void print_type(const T &) { std::cout << typeid(T).name() << '\n'; }

template <auto ... VALUE> void print_types_0() { (print_type(VALUE), ...); }

int main()
{
    print_types_0<0u, 0ll>(); // prints "j x " (gcc 13.2.0)
}
```

So, I was expecting the code below to work as well:

```cpp
template <unsigned U> void vtemplate()      { std::cout << "unsigned "; }

template <long long LL> void vtemplate()    { std::cout << "long long "; }

template <auto ... VALUE> void print_types_1() { (vtemplate<VALUE>(), ...); }

int main()
{
    print_types_1<1u, 1ll>(); // error!
}
```

But it fails due to ambiguity:

```
In instantiation of 'void print_types_1() [with auto ...VALUE = {1, 1}]':
  required from here
error: call of overloaded 'vtemplate<1>()' is ambiguous
template <auto ... VALUE> void print_types_1() { (vtemplate<VALUE>(), ...); }
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
note: candidate: 'void vtemplate() [with unsigned int U = 1]'
template <unsigned U> void vtemplate()      { std::cout << "unsigned "; }
                           ^~~~~~~~~
note: candidate: 'void vtemplate() [with long long int LL = 1]'
template <long long LL> void vtemplate()     { std::cout << "long long "; }        
                             ^~~~~~~~~
```

I'm not sure why it fails. My guess is that there's no such thing as "*template-value overload*", and even if `1u` and `1ll` are rightfully detected as `unsigned` and `long long` by the compiler, both values can be cast to each other's type, hence both `vtemplate` instances are equally valid. On the other hand, it works for `print_types_0` because each value is a better match to the function argument, and so there's no ambiguity.

I'm not sure if my explanation is correct. I was expecting `print_types_0` and `print_types_1` to behave almost the same.

Is there a way to achieve this "*value-template*" overload?

Comment: You might get rid of variadic to see the issue [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E3TrjYxj7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload resolution starts by converting each function template in the overload set into a function or else discarding it if template argument deduction fails, but the check for **better implicit conversion sequences** applies only to *function* arguments/parameters.  The closest analog for template parameters is **partial ordering**, but that too relies on the ordinary parameter types and so cannot disambiguate based on a template parameter that must be explicitly specified.

You can approximate this interface by deducing the template argument from a **stateless function parameter**:

```
template<auto> struct constant {};

template <unsigned U> void vtemplate(constant<U>)    { std::cout << "unsigned "; }
template <long long LL> void vtemplate(constant<LL>) { std::cout << "long long "; }

template <auto ... VALUE> void print_types_1() { (vtemplate(constant<VALUE>()), ...); }
```